# Android environment variable and parent-child activities

Tags: android, environment-variables

In Android, i am trying to figure out how can one activity see info changed by another

to be more precise - the first activity changes the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.

then activates a second activity which in turn reads that environment variable value.

the value is not what i expect.

two scenarios:

1. The second activity is in the same application as the first activity, the environment variable value is blank.
2. The second activity is in a different application from the first activity, the environment variable value is the usual (didn't received the change): /system/lib:vendor/lib

i am using:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("Package", "Class name");
startActivity(i);
```

to start the second activity.

does anyone know a way that the second activity will see the changes made by the first one?

thank for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does anyone know a way that the second activity will see the changes made by the first one?

Fortunately, that is not possible. At most, you are affecting the environment variable in your own process -- a Android app cannot change the environment variables in another app's process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will drop that subject